# Size of array of std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, size

I would like to check the `size()` or number of `rows` in an array of `std::vector()`.

I have vector like

```
std::vector<int> vec[3];
```

`vec.size()` does not work with the above vector declaration.

Comment: You want `std::distance(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec))`. In C++17, you want `std::size(vec)`.

Comment: You can use `sizeof(vec)/sizeof(std::vector<int>)`.

Comment: I think he means he wants `vec[0].size() + vec[1].size() + vec[2].size()`. In case this is really what needed, beware that the calculation above will be difference to `vec[0].capacity() + vec[1].capacity() + vec[2].capacity()`

Comment: @kerrek. Thanks, as I have declared array of vectors, I want to check the number of rows, i.e number of vectors

Comment: @AaghazHussain: Correct, which is what the expressions I gave you do.

Comment: If all the rows are expected to have the same length, you will find performance is much better if you define a `vec2D` class which has an `at(x,y)` function, and a private linear vector.  This means one allocation rather than n, and much better cache locality.  (Of course, if this is a quick exercise - carry on.)

Comment: @KerrekSB . Thanks works fine.

Comment: @MartinBonner . Length may vary.

Comment: You don't have a "two dimensional vector" (whatever that is.) You have an array of vectors. I edited the title, but you may want to fix the body of the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As for why `vec.size()` does not work, it's because `vec` is not a vector, it's an *array* (of vectors), and arrays in C++ are not objects (in the OOP sense that they are not instances of a class) and therefore have no member functions.

If you want to get the result `3` when doing `vec.size()` then you either have to use e.g. [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array<std::vector<int>, 3> vec;
std::cout << "vec.size() = " << vec.size() << '\n';  // Will output 3
```

Or if you don't have `std::array` then use a vector of vectors and set the size by calling the correct [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(3);
std::cout << "vec.size() = " << vec.size() << '\n';  // Will output 3
```

Comment: Arrays are still objects regardless if they are user defined types or not.

Comment: @Galik Arrays are not object in the typical object-oriented sense, where you have classes and objects (instances of classes). The C++ specification also calls other things objects, including arrays, which could be kind of confusing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do i need the size of vector i.e `vec(3)` at compilation time or run time, so as to accept the size of vector through command line

Comment: @AaghazHussain The size you pass to the constructor can be a variable that is set at runtime. Or you can just leave it without size, and call e.g. [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) at a later stage, or just push back a new element as usual.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing inherent in `std::vector<int> vec[3];` to say where the first or second indexing operation constitutes "rows" vs. "columns" - it's all a matter of your own perspective as a programmer.  That said, if you consider this to have 3 rows, you can retrieve that number using...

```
 std::extent<decltype(vec)>::value
```

...for which you'll need to `#include <type_traits>`.  See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/extent).

Anyway, `std::array<>` is specifically designed to provide a better, more consistent interface - and will already be familiar from `std::vector`:

```
std::array<std::vector<int>, 3> vec;
...use vec.size()...
```

(Consistency is particularly important if you want templated code to handle both vectors and arrays.)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int Nrows = 3;
int Ncols = 4
std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(Nrows);
for(int k=0;k<Nrows;k++)
   vec[k].resize(Ncols);

...

auto Nrows = vec.size();
auto Ncols = (Nrows > 0 ? vec[0].size() : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use `sizeof(vec[0])/sizeof(vec)` or `sizeof(vec)/sizeof(vector<int>)`